# Facebook SDK: client_pages call returns "PENDING" even though permissions were granted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We need to be able to create ads (programmatically) for our clients' pages.

We connect the app to Facebook on the client side, thusly:

```
FB.init({
        appId,
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v8.0',
    });
    FB.login(response => {
        console.log('FB.login ', response);
    }, {
        scope: 'ads_management,pages_show_list,business_management,pages_manage_ads',
        return_scopes: true
    });
```

The "ads_management" scope results in the user being presented with a dialog allowing him to select pages for which he wishes to grant our app permission to advertise.
So far, so good.

Now, our current understanding is that, in order to use this permission, we need to:

curl
-F "page_id=<PAGE_ID>"
-F "permitted_tasks=['ADVERTISE']"
-F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
"https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/<BUSINESS_ID>/client_pages"

The <ACCESS_TOKEN> in question here is one that we have obtained for our business's app-scoped system user, from here
https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users/100053095133371
The <BUSINESS_ID> is ours, namely this one: 211256229451447
<PAGE_ID> is the ID of the end user's page: 101848131661824

Unfortunately, the response we get is :

{"access_status":"PENDING"}

It seems that this response indicates that the end user is meant to approve this request manually.  This is strange, as the user has already approved the ads_management scope on connecting his account (see above). It seems that he is now required to approve access for the business (not the app this time?) manually, using the Facebook web interface.

So, what are we doing wrong here?  How can we obtain permission to advertise for the user's page?

Note that our support request to FB has been summarily closed without resolution, which is fairly normal.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3349788308467923/

Comment: _“hat the end user is meant to approve this request manually”_ - sounds like it, yeah, especially considering that https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/pending_client_pages/ says, _“The business requested access to these pages and waits for client approval.”_ - so as long as you get the page ID shown when requesting that endpoint, I’d assume that there’s still an manual step to perform on the user side.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/pages: _“If you make an AGENCY claim, but do not have proper Page permissions, the response is PENDING. The Admin for that Page can log in and grant the access, deny it, or report the claim as a spam.”_